# better way to build numpy array for ta-lib

Tags: python, numpy

I'm hopeful someone can save me from myself.  I'm trying to create an input array for TA-Lib that needs to be a numpy.ndarray.  My original data is in a list of dict as floats.  I have the following code working, but it seems to be a terrible way to do this.  I'm trying to create the ndarray with length "blocks" of floats, then fill it with list of dict values where "results" looks like this truncated version:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
import talib
from talib.abstract import Function
from matplotlib.dates import epoch2num

results=[{'min': 23.154066666666665, 'max': 23.298, 'price': 23.257773259460716, 'amount': 95.17532800000002, 'date': 1389336300, 'close': 23.22373, 'open': 23.26123287671233}, 
{'min': 23.134200000000003, 'max': 23.339819999999996, 'price': 23.271289011315073, 'amount': 2131.7753154199972, 'date': 1389336120, 'close': 23.26123287671233, 'open': 23.25126987951807}]
    open = np.ndarray(shape=(blocks), dtype=float)
    close = np.ndarray(shape=(blocks), dtype=float)
    high = np.ndarray(shape=(blocks), dtype=float)
    low = np.ndarray(shape=(blocks), dtype=float)
    volume = np.ndarray(shape=(blocks), dtype=float)
    ts = np.ndarray(shape=(blocks), dtype=float)
    inputs = {}
    for i in range(len(results)):
        open[i] = results[i].get('open')
        high[i] = results[i].get('max')
        low[i] = results[i].get('min')
        close[i] = results[i].get('close')
        volume[i] = results[i].get('amount')
        ts[i] = epoch2num(results[i].get('date'))
    inputs['open'] = open
    inputs['high'] = high
    inputs['low'] = low
    inputs['close'] = close
    inputs['volume'] = volume
    inputs['ts'] = ts

    sma = Function('sma')
    input_arrays = sma.get_input_arrays()
    for key in input_arrays.keys():
        input_arrays[key] = inputs[key]
    output = sma(input_arrays, timeperiod=3)
```

I'm following the brief api documentation for ta-lib, in creating this inputs_array for valid fields for the 'sma' function and this works, however it is the ugliest thing I've seen in a while.  Since I know the block size ahead of time, it seems like I shouldn't have to do all this iteration, but I'm just learning Python so I'm hopeful someone can show me a better/faster way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions

```
results = ...

inputs['open'] = np.array([r.get('open') for r in results], dtype=float)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inputs = {key: np.array([result[key] for result in results]) for key in results[0]}
for new, old in [('high', 'max'), ('low', 'min'), ('volume', 'amount')]:
    inputs[new] = inputs.pop(old)
inputs['ts'] = np.array(map(epoch2num, inputs.pop('date')))
del inputs['price']
```

The main thing is the first line, the rest only handles renaming, etc. This however assumes that the keys in all the dictionaries in `results` are always the same and that there is at least one result. Please comment if these requirements are not fit.